# How to Detach Glyphs with FontForge Python?

Tags: python, fontforge

In the FontForge GUI under the 'Encoding' menu there is an option 'Detach Glyphs.' Can I do this in Python?

More specifically, in my Python script when I remove a glyph that is attached to another glyph, both are cleared. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround from here https://sourceforge.net/p/fontforge/mailman/message/29723762/

It is essentially:

```
font.selection.select("a")           #select glyph
font.copy()
for i in font.selection.byGlyphs:
    font.removeGlyph(i)
font.selection.select("a")
font.paste()
```